# Update random row in DB using Flask-Sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been trying to update a randomly selected row in my Sqlite database using Flask and the Flask-Sqlalchemy. I have just a few rows in the database with columns called "word", "yes", and "no", where word is a string and yes and no are integers. There are two buttons on the "vote" view, yes and no. When a button is pressed, the appropriate code executes, should increment the yes or no column, and the view is updated with a new random word from the Word table.

```
@app.route("/vote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def vote():
    #Get random row from database
    query = db.session.query(Word)
    rowCount = int(query.count())
    row = query.offset(int(rowCount*random.random())).first()

    #POST

    # If "yes" button is pressed, increment yes column in database
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form.get("yes"):
            row.yes += 1
            db.session.commit()
            return render_template("vote.html", row=row)
    # otherwise increment no column
        elif request.form.get("no"):
            row.no += 1
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for("vote"))

    #GET

    # on get request, render vote.html
    return render_template("vote.html", row=row)
```

This code is working, but the yes and no columns are only updated when the view comes back around to the random word the next time. If I close the browser right after clicking a button, the database is not incremented. I think this has something to do with db.session.commit(), or something about the session. It seems like:

```
row.yes += 1
```

is saved in the session object, but only committed when that database row is queried the next time. This code DID work when I replaced the query at the top of the method with:

```
row = Word.query.get(4)
```

which returns the row with id of 4. With this query, the yes or no column are updated immediately.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Your increments are vulnerable to race conditions. You should let the database handle the increment for you. `row.yes = Word.yes + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all. I figured out the problem. The database incrementing was actually working fine, but I wasn't incrementing the correct rows. The problem was that I generated a random row from the database on each call of the vote() method, which meant that I got a random value for the GET request, and a different random value for the POST request, and ended up incrementing that different random value in the POST request.

I separated the logic out into two methods for the "/vote" route, getWord() and vote(), and created a randRow() method for the row generation. I needed to store the random row that gets generated when getWord() is called, so I used session variables so I could access the random row from the vote() method. It's a bit verbose, but seems to work.

Anyone have a better idea about how to achieve this?

```
@app.route('/vote', methods=["GET"])
def getWord():
    wordObj = randRow()
    session['word'] = wordObj.word
    session['yesVotes'] = wordObj.yes
    session['noVotes'] = wordObj.no
    return render_template("vote.html", word=session['word'], yesVotes=session['yesVotes'], noVotes=session['noVotes'])

@app.route('/vote', methods=["POST"])
def vote():
    # store session 'word' in word variable
    # look up word in database and store object in wordObj
    word = session['word']
    wordObj = Word.query.filter_by(word=word).first()
    # check button press on vote view, increment yes or no column
    # depending on which button was pressed
    if request.form.get("yes"):
        wordObj.yes = wordObj.yes + 1
    elif request.form.get("no"):
        wordObj.no = wordObj.no + 1
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("getWord"))

###### HELPERS ######

# returns a random row from the database
def randRow():
    rowId = Word.query.order_by(func.random()).first().id
    row = Word.query.get(rowId)
    return row
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the update into the session before the commit, using code like this:

```
[...]
    row.yes += 1
    db.session.add(row)
    db.session.commit()
[...]
```

That's the pattern that I use for a basic update in Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Comment: You don't need to add things to the session if they were loaded through it. `Model.query` does that.